# Problem creating SSH tunnel on linux

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, ssh-tunneling, vnc

I'm following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-connecting-the-vnc-desktop-securely) to setup VNC on my DigitalOcean droplet.

Everything works fine up to step 3. When I try to create an SSH connection on my local computer using `ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C -N -l sammy your_server_ip` in my terminal, nothing happens: [image: terminal screenshot]

I'm using Linux mint 19.01
Droplet is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: ehm...  You now have the tunnel running. The guide says "Once the tunnel is running, use a VNC client to connect to localhost:5901. " So, what happens if you start (for example in a second terminal) `vncviewer 127.0.0.1::5901`?

Comment: @LjmDullaart [link](http://tinypic.com/r/28bh2kl/9)

Comment: Please answer questions in comments by improving you initial post...

Comment: @LjmDullaart I got it to work by installing and using vncviewer instead of gvncviewer. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this step, you set-up a tunnel. When you start-up ssh in tunnel-mode, it will just run in tunnel-mode, providing no additional output.

After this step, you can start:

```
vncviewer 127.0.0.1::5901
```

to get a connection.

Note that the `5901` is the port number that you used to set-up your tunnel. The syntax for `gvncviewer` is different; the part in the command-line after the `:` there is used to specify the display, not the port number as far as I can tell (I don't use `gvncviewer`)

Answer (score 2):

The `-N` option will disable the shell. `man ssh`:

```
-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.
```

The digitalocean [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-connecting-the-vnc-desktop-securely):

> while the `-N` switch tells ssh that we don't want to execute a remote command.

Answer (score 0):

worked after installing vncviewer and running `vncviewer localhost:5901`